# Can i use regex within a pytest expression

Tags: python, pytest

Is it possible to locate tests with pytest using pattern matching, for example i want to find all tests that begin with the letters from a-m

i have been trying things like

```
pytest -m ^[aA-mM]

pytest --collectonly -k test_^[aA-mM] --quiet
```

Not got it to work so far, is this possible?

Comment: No, this is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't seem possible according to [pytest doc](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/usage.html).
Have you considered marking the tests instead?
This helps with filtering them out when you run pytest.
More info about marking could be found in the [pytest doc about markers](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/example/markers.html)...
[or another tutorial about it](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pytest/pytest_grouping_the_tests.htm)

But in short, for example:

1. just add `@pytest.mark.foo` onto some tests, and `@pytest.mark.bar` to others
2. run `pytest -m foo` to run the tests marked as `foo` only.

Answer (score 0):

I recently wanted to do exactly this and released the `pytest-regex` plugin available as:

- https://github.com/tylerjereddy/pytest-regex and https://pypi.org/project/pytest-regex/
- `pip install pytest-regex`

It works by selecting tests with node ids that match your regular expression, where a node id looks like this: `path/to/test_module.py::TestClass::test_name[parameter_value]`

Let's try it on a Python project with a pretty large test suite, like SciPy, using your chosen test selection regex, narrowed down to a smaller range of letters to simplify the output.

`pytest -v --pyargs scipy --regex ".*test_[a-bA-B]+$"`

```
linalg/tests/test_blas.py::TestTRMM::test_ab PASSED                                                                              [ 20%]
ndimage/tests/test_measurements.py::Test_measurements_stats::test_a PASSED                                                       [ 40%]
ndimage/tests/test_measurements.py::Test_measurements_stats::test_b PASSED                                                       [ 60%]
stats/tests/test_distributions.py::TestGenpareto::test_ab PASSED                                                                 [ 80%]
stats/tests/test_distributions.py::TestFrozen::test_ab PASSED                                                                    [100%]
```

There's some upstream discussion about adding a regex-accepting command line option to `pytest` proper someday, but not sure which direction that decision will land: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/11024